How to use multiple where condition in Laravel?
I want to fetch data from the database using laravel by using multiple conditions. The query must look for the different conditions in same columns and grab the result.
Table looks like this



Item
Position
Gender




A
All
All


B
Permanent
All


C
All
Female


D
All
Male


E
Temporary
All



I want to fetch the data where the position category can either be All or user-specific and gender can either be all or user-specific. The user-specific position and gender values can be obtained from the logged in user's details.
If user position is "Permanent" and gender is "Male" then the results should look like



Item
Position
Gender




A
All
All


B
Permanent
All


D
All
Male



I need a query to get the result.

Are you going to do self join? if not then share the two tables name  tell  which columns between those table are related?

The data has to come from a single table only so there's no join required.

this All and user specific filter coming from request ?

Does this answer your question? Laravel using WHERE orWHERE

Please add the code you have tried in your question. This is well documented.

You can use whereIn():
$items = Item::whereIn('position', ['All', $userPosition])
        ->whereIn('gender', ['All', $userGender])
        ->get();

which will produce the following prepared statement:
select * from `items` where `position` in (?, ?) and `gender` in (?, ?)

and then execute it with the provided values - ['All', 'Permanent', 'All', 'Male']

You can use the Eloquent ORM to build a query with multiple conditions. So Firstly get details of the logged user by using Auth and pass the params to where condition. Check below the code.
use App\Models\Item;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$userPosition = Auth::user()->position;
$userGender = Auth::user()->gender;

$items = Item::where(function($query) use ($userPosition) {
        $query->where('position', 'All')
              ->orWhere('position', $userPosition);
    })
    ->where(function($query) use ($userGender) {
        $query->where('gender', 'All')
              ->orWhere('gender', $userGender);
    })
    ->get();


This solved the issue I was getting. The code came as a rescue.
